# .bat file to create a complex string variable with special characters

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a single string variable by concatenating multiple strings. The final string i need is as below

```
<Workspace name="RealTimeRiskUSD_UA" path="C:\workspace" IsAdmin="false" />
```

This is what i tried.

```
echo off
set path1="<Workspace "
set name="name="RealTimeRiskUSD_UA"" 
set path2="path="C:\workspace" IsAdmin="false" />"
set fullpath=%path1%%name%%path2%
echo %path1%
echo %name%
echo %path2%
echo %fullpath%
```

I also tried using the below link to remove the double quotes from each string but does not work
http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the extended syntax of SET. 
set "var=content".

This escapes special characters, but the quotes aren't part of the string.

```
echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "path1=<Workspace " 
set "name=name="RealTimeRiskUSD_UA"" 
set "path2=path="C:\workspace" IsAdmin="false" />" 
set "fullpath=%path1%%name%%path2%"
echo !fullpath!
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your quick response! Please could you tell me difference between !fullpath! and %fullpath% in this case?

Comment: It's delayed expansion, the advantage of the delayed expansion is here that special characters can be used without any side effekts