# Using set to set special characters does not seem to work [Bat]

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a simple batch file for outputting jars on request
So when i write the argument it must look something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533115/run-30-jar-from-batch-and-save-the-output-result-for-each-jar)

But instead of writing `< "input%%~nj.txt" > "output%%~nj.txt"` directly I want to use a variable so I can output to a file if I want.

I have tried [escaping special characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) and [set syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318614/bat-file-to-create-a-complex-string-variable-with-special-characters) methods 
But so far no luck

Here is my code snippet

```
::per is a variable about setting input or not
::per gets changed to a string after being checked, to be used in java as an arg.
::echo test works so I am sure that there are no errors on that section
IF [%per%]==[1] (set "per= < "input!pth!.txt" > "output%pth%.txt""&echo test)

::testing if per works as intended
::must show per: < "input!pth!.txt" > "output%pth%.txt"
Echo per: %per%

::per shows 1 instead of < "input!pth!.txt" > "output%pth%.txt"
::filename is the name of the jar with .jar
java -Xmx1024M -jar %filename%%per%
```

So how can i set per `variable` to `< "input%%~nj.txt" > "output%%~nj.txt"` ?

Comment: You forget delayed expansion on the variable.

Comment: Ah well i forgot to add it in the snippet but i have delayedexpansions enabled

Comment: I think he means instead of `Echo per: %per%` you should use `Echo per: !per!` to test whether it works as intended.

Comment: Hmm let me give it a hit will update in a sec

Comment: as i thought since !per! is not declared as variable echo shouts !per! not %per% :)